# Costruction avec l'adverbe « là »

Tags: sens, expressions-idiomatiques, formulation-idiomatique, adverbes, france

*La Petite Fadette*, George Sand

Le sens dans la construction en relief ci-dessous veut que le premier « là » soit mis à la place d'un certain endroit et le second à la place d'un autre. Cette construction (« là comme là ») n'est pas dans le [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/l%C3%A0), ni dans le Wiktionnaire, ce qui porte à croire plus fermement que ce n'est pas un idiotisme.

> Il fut étonné de trouver plus d’eau que de
> coutume, d’autant plus qu’il entendait le bruit des écluses qu’on avait ouvertes depuis une bonne heure. Pourtant, comme il voyait bien la lumière
> de la croisée à la Fadette, il se risqua. Mais, au bout de deux pas, il avait
> de l’eau plus haut que le genou et il se retira, jugeant qu’il s’était trompé.
> Il essaya un peu plus haut et un peu plus bas, et, **là comme là**, il trouva
> le creux encore davantage.

Il n'y aurait dans cet usage rien d'idiosyncratique à l'œuvre de Sand puisqu'à peu près à la même époque (1898) on retrouve cette construction au moins une fois. Elle est néanmoins rare.

> ([Les origines de la Compagnie de Jésus: Ignace et Lainez](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Les_origines_de_la_Compagnie_de_J%C3%A9sus/IqpFAAAAIAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&bsq=%22l%C3%A0+comme+l%C3%A0%22&dq=%22l%C3%A0+comme+l%C3%A0%22&printsec=frontcover) ) Là comme là, chez les Jésuites comme chez les Kouan, ils forment des apôtres, des martyrs, des saints ; mais aussi des ambitieux, des politiques, des espions et des fanatiques. Là comme là, les chefs possèdent et pratiquent ...

À cette même époque on trouve l'utilisation de « [ici comme là](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22ici%20comme%20l%C3%A0%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr) » en nombre important et de nos jours c'est une construction qui nous est familière. « Là comme ici » se trouve aussi, mais moins fréquemment.

Est-ce que l'on peut juger cette construction  toujours acceptable, ou, pour être plus pragmatique, donné la situation d'un correcteur de devoirs de français qui lit cette construction dans la rédaction de l'un de ses élèves, doit-il porter un jugement sur le sens et considérer cette combinaison comme valide ou non ? Quels seraient pour le texte de Sand, où aucune des occurrence de « là »  ne peut être remplacée par « ici », des substituts qui remédieraient à la notion d'indifférenciation qui se dégage de la construction initiale ?  (Il me semble que « à chaque essai » serait une possibilité.)

Vu le contexte, est-ce que cette construction n'aurait pas été négligée en tant qu'idiotisme signifiant « où que ce soit » ?

Comment: Pourquoi y  remédier ? Parce qu'on ne dit pas « le canari et le canari sont en bonne santé »,  mais « les canaris sont en bonne santé. », ou « les deux canaris sont en bonne santé ». De plus, si c'est un idiotisme,  il faut une définition dans un dictionnaire, et il n'y en a pas.

Comment: @CrissyFroth-Seapickle tout comme un canari et un autre canari ne sont pas le même canari. C'est sans logique, ça crêve les  yeux. Quel est ce principe de coordination ? il n'y en a pas. « à nice comme à Nice » est du  non sens, et « à la guerre comme à la guerre » a beaucoup de sens, oui, mais c'est un idiotisme, à définir dans un dictionnaire.

Comment: @CrissyFroth-Seapickle Je ne vois aucun exemple dans ce que je puisse me rappeler. Au TLFi, quelle entrée permet de voir ça ? Il n'y a rien, ni à « comme » ni à « là ». Il n'est fait aucune mention de pointeur. Le mot [pointeur](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointeur) n'est pas un terme de la grammaire française. « Comme » n'est qu'un adverbe.

Comment: « Le morph. [_comme_](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/comme), grâce à l'idée de compar., de similitude (« de même que ») sous-jacente à celle de conformité, joue le rôle d'un coordonnant. » (TLFi). Ta prescription comme ton analyse comme ta compréhension sont réductrices et me dépriment. Là comme là comme là.

Comment: @CrissyFroth-Seapickle Merci, oui, je comprend ce rôle médiocre de coordonnant ; néanmoins, il n'y a pas de lien de cette propriété vers celle qui serait la possibilité d'utiliser un seul mot pour deux choses ; d'abord il n'existe que de rares cas de ça et ils sont très spéciaux ; ce n'est pas souhaitable et  c'est désagréable : on ne sait pas quoi est quoi. Voilà par exemple un cas, « quoi est quoi », mais je crois que c'est un idiotisme. Ne me parlez pas de ma prescription, vous faites de la prescription toute la journée ; décréter  « là comme là » correct c'est de la prescription.

Comment: À chacun sa prescription, _fair enough_. Mais oui on le sait quoi est quoi, par référence/référent (c'était ça le « pointeur »). Un peu comme avec un pronom, mais sans l'accord et simplement avec le nombre d'éléments.

Comment: @CrissyFroth-Seapickle Je ne vois pas d'autre explication que l'impossibilité d'une analyse grammaticale et le passage à la justification en invoquant l'idée d'idiotisme.

Comment: Deux adverbes désignant deux lieux, situations ou choses, coordonnés, incident, pouvant être remplacé par _y_ chez Sand ou par _autant les X que les Y_ pour l'autre exemple. La difficulté que tu y vois n'est pas grammaticale, c'est plutôt une impression d'équivoque.

Comment: Il n'y a pas deux adverbes mais deux occurrences du même adverbe. C'est grammatical en cela que donné un adverbe on doit s'informer de quoi il modifie, ce qui entraine une question de sémantique (quel est le référent du mot modifié) ; ce ne serait  pas purement grammatical alors et ce serait plutôt grammatico-sémantique.